# React not adding additional refs in loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

refs in list component remains at 10, even when adding another item to prop in parent component. Additional added inputs when clicking the button in the list component do not get a ref assigned.

```
const App = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState(new Array(10).fill({}));
  
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <ItemList items={items} />
      <button onClick={() => setItems([...items, {}])}>Add item</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
const List = ({items}) => {
  const refs = useRef(items.map(i => React.createRef()));
  
  return (
    <div className='List'>
      {items.map(item, i) => (
        <Item ref={refs.current[i]} item={item} key={i} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
const Item = React.forwardRef(({item}, ref) => {
  return (
    <div className='Item'>
      <input ref={ref}/>
    </div>
  );
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the new ref using a `useEffect` hook inside your `ItemList` component

```
 useEffect(() => {
    refs.current.push(React.createRef())
 },[items])
```